# oracle sql convert all rows to columns

Tags: oracle11g

I want to flip all rows to columns. So if have following 5 columns
with 3 data rows

```
ACCT_ID       NAME           PHONE              MOBILE      ALTERNATIVE_NAME

01          JOE BROWN        0456-9992-6666    07767828432       ZOE BROWN

02          GILL SHARP       0456-9992-6666    07763928432       BILL SHARP

03          ZAC LOWE         0236-9992-5644    07663925672       LUKE LOWE
```

I want the result set to look as follows. So have 3 columns and 5 rows.

COL headings (COL1 - COL3) are only added to make clearer, i don't need
columns headings

```
COL1                        COL2                             COL3

01                           02                               03

JOE BROWN                    GILL SHARP                      ZAC LOWE   

0456-9992-6666               0456-9992-6666                  0236-9992-5644

07767828432                  07763928432                     07663925672

ZOE BROWN                    BILL SHARP                      LUKE LOWE
```

I tried using PIVOT on one column (acct_id)

```
Select *
from

(
  select ACCT_ID 
  from TABLE 
  ) 
pivot

(
   max(ACCT_ID) as ACCT_ID 
   for ACCT_ID in ('01','02','03') 
)
```

This returns following

```
'01'_ACCT_ID    '02'_ACCT_ID      '03'_ACCT_ID

01                  02                  03
```

Which is on the right track. Just need extending to include the  other 4 columns     (NAME,PHONE,MOBILE,ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT), listed under the associated acct_id.
So end up with 5 rows.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Please format any code to make your post easier to read for others.

Comment: ctrl+k will help to format as code, thus improving readability

Answer (score 0):

You could brute-force it with a series of case expressions:

```
select max(case when acct_id = '01' then acct_id end) as col1,
       max(case when acct_id = '02' then acct_id end) as col2,
       max(case when acct_id = '03' then acct_id end) as col3
from your_table
union all
select max(case when acct_id = '01' then name end),
       max(case when acct_id = '02' then name end),
       max(case when acct_id = '03' then name end)
from your_table
union all
select max(case when acct_id = '01' then phone end),
       max(case when acct_id = '02' then phone end),
       max(case when acct_id = '03' then phone end)
from your_table
... repeat for other columns

COL1           COL2           COL3          
-------------- -------------- --------------
01             02             03            
JOE BROWN      GILL SHARP     ZAC LOWE      
0456-9992-6666 0456-9992-6666 0236-9992-5644
...
```

Or you could unpivot and re-pivot, which is messy and probably doing more work than is really necessary:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (
  select t.*, t.acct_id as col_id
  from your_table t
)
unpivot
(
  value for heading in (acct_id, name, phone, mobile, alternative_name)
)
pivot
(
  max(value) for col_id in ('01' as col1, '02' as col2, '03' as col3)
)
order by case heading when 'ACCT_ID' then 1 when 'NAME' then 2 when 'PHOEN' then 3
                      when 'MOBILE' then 4 when 'ALTERNATIVE_NAME' then 5 end

COL1           COL2           COL3          
-------------- -------------- --------------
01             02             03            
JOE BROWN      GILL SHARP     ZAC LOWE      
07767828432    07763928432    07663925672   
ZOE BROWN      BILL SHARP     LUKE LOWE     
0456-9992-6666 0456-9992-6666 0236-9992-5644
```

The subquery to add the dummy `col_id` expression is only there so you can picot on the acct_id and also include it in the result.

If you want to include the original column names as a heading column in the final result, add that to the first select list:

```
select heading, col1, col2, col3
from (
...
```

This only works if you know there will be (at most) three rows (and is based on fixed account IDs, though that is fixable); if you don't know how many columns your final result will need to have then you need to look at dynamic SQL.

Comment: What would dynamic SQL look like using unpivot and pivot, if have fixed number of starting columns i.e. 5, but any number of starting rows. I used acct_id '01, '02, '03' in example but acct_id could be any value so wouldn't be able to reference the values in the sql and can 1 to nth of rows.

Comment: @JSQL - not sure why I didn't reply at the time; it would have said that a dynamic approach is too far from your original question, and too much to add to this answer (never mind as a comment), so you'd need to ask a separate question about that. But I can see you did anyway - I didn't see that at the time, but I've added an answer to that now in case it's still something you need.